# Ubuntu - accessing folder with two groups

Tags: ubuntu, groups

I have a two groups: `www-data` and `editors` groups. Consider I have a folder `/home/mydata/` and I need to allow access folder both groups.
I have tried:

```
chown -R www-data;editors /home/mydata
```

But `www-data` as user is not enough - website requires a whole group `www-data` to access folder. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with `chown`'s  "classic" User-Group-Other permissions and will need to enable [ACL](http://linux.die.net/man/5/acl)'s to define more fine-grained discretionary access rights for files and directories.

Explaining those is a bit beyond the scope of ServerFault but this HowTo may be of interest: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs